# How should I mount a raspberry pi model B rev 1

Tags: case

I'm looking to include a pi in a project and investigating ways to mount it into the project enclosure.

I don't want to damage the pi as I may want to remove it in the future so things like hot glue are out

However I don't want the PI moving about if the enclosure is moved too quickly

Comment: use the mounting holes on the board, thats what they are there for.

Comment: As @craig points out the rev 1 didn't have the mounting holes. hence my question.

Comment: learn something new everyday, up voted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: The Model B rev 1 does not have mounting holes they were added in the rev 2.

Two options for mounting the B Rev1

1. Edge mounting stand-offs like [these from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1116)
2. A friction fit case that does not need mounting holes:

   - https://www.adafruit.com/products/1326
   - https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11623 -- This case has holes you can use to mount it to something.

Comment: Those edge mount stand-offs are just what I'm looking for, thank you.